# How to capture newlines from command substitution output in fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

In bash, newline characters are preserved through command substitution:

```
$ TEST="$(echo 'a
  b
  c
  ')" && echo "$TEST"
# →
a
b
c
```

However, when I try to do the same in fish shell, the newline characters get converted into spaces:

```
$ set TEST (echo "a
  b
  c
  "); and echo "$TEST"
# →
a b c
```

How to make fish save the newline characters as newlines?

Comment: Fish shell tries way too hard to be different. I'd give anything for a shell with bash as the scripting language and fish's interactive features like syntax highlighting and history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conceptually, they are not converted into spaces: you are getting a list!

```
> echo -e "1\n2\n3" > foo
> cat foo
1
2
3
> set myFoo (cat foo)
> echo $myFoo
1 2 3
> echo $myFoo[0..2]
1 2
```

Therefore we apply the machinery available for [lists](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_lists); for instance, [joining with a separator](https://sourceforge.net/p/fish/mailman/message/33644843/) (note the extra backspace to get rid of undesirable spaces):

```
> echo {\b$myFoo}\n
1
2
3
 # extra newline here
```

This is not ideal; [string](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string) does it better:

```
> string join \n $myFoo
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Exact issue discussed on fish users mailing list: Discussed on fish users mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/p/fish/mailman/message/33644843/

You have to modify the IFS variable to do this:

```
$ set out (seq 5)
$ echo "$out"
1 2 3 4 5

$ set oldIFS "$IFS"
$ set IFS ""
$ set out (seq 5)
$ echo "$out"
1
2
3
4
5
$ set IFS "$oldIFS"
```

Comment: Thank you for he feedback. It works like a charm, but brings some errors from `fish_prompt` while `IFS` is set to `""`. Do you know of any plans to make it possible to do it in a one-liner and supress the errors?

Comment: There are some links to the fish issue tracker in that mailing list thread.